# syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'tblPlayerstatistics.MatchID = tblGameResults.MatchID COUNT tblPLayerStatistics.TwoPOinterMad.'

Tags: mysql

I am trying choose a player of the match by selecting a player who scored the highest number of points in one match. I have tried count to add the 2 pointer made and 3 pointer made and this is the only way to find out the highes score. Please Helpppp

```
SELECT tblPlayerStatistics.Player_ID_Number,
tblPlayerStatistics.TwoPointerMade,
tblPlayerStatistics.ThreePointerMade, 
MatchID
FROM tblPlayerStatistics
INNER JOIN tblGameResults ON tblPlayerStatistics.MatchID = tblGameResults.MatchID
COUNT tblPlayerStatistics.TwoPointerMade 
AND tblPlayerStatistics.ThreePointerMade
GROUP BY tblPlayerStatistics.Player_ID_Number;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error in query expression 'tblPlayerStatistcs.2\_Pointer\_Attempts'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22338182/syntax-error-in-query-expression-tblplayerstatistcs-2-pointer-attempts)

Answer (score 0):

You completely misunderstood how `COUNT` works and MySQL's query syntax. If you want to add up the amount of points made, you need to use `SUM`.

The query you want is:

```
SELECT
    tblPlayerStatistics.Player_ID_Number,
    SUM(tblPlayerStatistics.TwoPointerMade + tblPlayerStatistics.ThreePointerMade) AS points, 
    MatchID
FROM
    tblPlayerStatistics
    INNER JOIN tblGameResults ON tblPlayerStatistics.MatchID = tblGameResults.MatchID
GROUP BY
    tblPlayerStatistics.Player_ID_Number,
    MatchID;
```

That should get you started on the right path

Answer (score 0):

you could rename your table `tblPlayerStatistics` to `thisismytableofthePlayerStatisticsever`

try that:

```
   SELECT tblPlayerStatistics.Player_ID_Number,
   COUNT(tblPlayerStatistics.TwoPointerMade) as TwoPointerMade ,
   tblPlayerStatistics.ThreePointerMade, 
    MatchID
   FROM tblPlayerStatistics
   INNER JOIN tblGameResults ON tblPlayerStatistics.MatchID = tblGameResults.MatchID
   AND tblPlayerStatistics.ThreePointerMade
   GROUP BY tblPlayerStatistics.Player_ID_Number;
```

Comment: "you could rename your table": Why?

Comment: @EJP i was just joking , because he uses long names for nothing. you dont see what i suggest his to rename to ? very long :) , OMG i shouldnt explain it to you , you seems dont understand.

Comment: @echo_Me thanks for your help and i appreciate it. the joke was good to, i should really change the name. however it doesnt seem to work. It says that "JOIN expression not supported" and highlights the statement after AND. I will re-post this as a new question.